# Python - Perform an operation on an element of a tuple

Tags: python

I have a tuple `(x,y)` where `x` is a string and `y` is an integer.
Now I want to perform an operation on `y`, like `y += 1`, without wanting to create a new tuple. How can I do that?

Comment: `newtup = (oldtup[0], oldtup[1] + 1)`

Comment: I don't want to create a new tuple but want to update the old one without having to create a new tuple.

Comment: @uitty400 You cannot, `tuple` is an immutable container

Comment: Well you can't because tuples are **immutable** so you can give up on that idea

Comment: Why don't you use a `list` instead?

Comment: Actually I want to write my own dictionary class. Therefore I want to store (key, value) as tuples in a list. Now I don't know how I can increment the value of such a tuple.

Comment: Make an object then use: `obj.y += 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, so you can't directly modify the variable

```
>>> t = ('foobar', 7)
>>> t[1] += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    t[1] += 1
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

So you'd have to assign back a new tuple

```
>>> t = (t[0], t[1]+1)
>>> t
('foobar', 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't - tuples are immutable. Any attempt of changing an existing tuple would result in `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`.

What can be done is re-binding object name to a new tuple based on the previous one.

```
t = ('a', 1)
t = (t[0], t[1]+1)
assert t == ('a', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since the operation would mutate the tuple, which is not possible. Create a new tuple.

```
newtuple = (t[0], t[1] + 1)
```